# Selecting/Deselecting the option all from a select tag

Tags: html, jquery

I have a multi select drop down as follows:

```html
<select id="country" class="form-select" multiple name="country[]">
  <option selected value="">All</option>
  <option value="1">UK</option>
  <option value="2">USA</option>
  <option value="3">Germany</option>
  <option value="4">Australia</option>
</select>
```

So as you can see by default it would be the option 'All' which will be highlighted. What I am trying to do is to unselect the option 'All' if you select any other options.

Also if you select all the options then I just want to have the 'All' option selected.

Just to give an example, if I selected these following options:

All, UK, USA

Then it should be:

UK and USA

Another example would be, if I selected the following:

UK, USA, Germany and Australia

Then it should be :

All

If anyone could give me some advise how I could go about it, that would be great.

Comment: What have you tried so far script wise? shouldnt be so hard to do with a simple if statement

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged CSS, but anyway, there are hundreds of questions about selecting/deselecting options in `select` elements on Stack Overflow. Please show any research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Get values, update values, put values - which specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is really clunky UX, especially if I want all, except a value - I can't select all of them (except "all"), then unselect as this would unselect them all - might be better to put the [all] option *outside* the drop down (as a checkbox) then disable the drop down if [all] is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the following function on change of select menu:

```js
function _onCountrySelect() {
  var _option = jQuery("#country").val();
  
  if (_option[0] == "" && _option.length > 1) {
    jQuery("#country").val(_option.slice(1));
  }

  if ((_option[0] != "" && _option.length == jQuery("#country option").length - 1)) {
    jQuery("#country").val("");
  }
}

$('#country').on('change', _onCountrySelect);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="country" class="form-select" multiple name="country[]">
  <option selected value="">All</option>
  <option value="1">UK</option>
  <option value="2">USA</option>
  <option value="3">Germany</option>
  <option value="4">Australia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: onchange="_onCountrySelect()" add this in select tag

Comment: Or be smart and use `jQuery("#country").on("change", _onCountrySelect);` after defining `_onCountrySelect`